# What's the best hierarchical module path for an OpenCL-Haskell library?

Tags: haskell, opencl, hackage, haskell-platform

I'm creating a OpenCL high-level haskell library. Where's the best path in haskell tree for put it? I think it should be outside of `Graphics` subtree but I dont know where to put it.

It's based on Jeff Heard OpenCLRaw (He put that one on `System.OpenCL.Raw.V10`).

**Update:**
I just started a repository, http://github.com/zhensydow/opencl

**Update:** Options that I propose (and fomr answers)

- System.GPU.OpenCL
- Control.Parallel.OpenCL
- Foreign.OpenCL

Comment: -- This file is part of Skema?

Comment: @monadic, not it isn't. Skema is a own project that need to use Opencl. Thanks for notice it. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about putting it in `Control.Parallel`? The [`haskell-mpi`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-mpi) package uses `Control.Parallel.MPI`, and there's also the commonly used `Control.Parallel.Strategies` so it seems like an appropriate prefix.

**Shameless plug:** I wrote a small script for fun to extract the hierarchical module tree from all packages on Hackage. It might be useful for seeing what hierarchical modules other packages use. I'll clean up the code and release it some time in the future. For now, here's [the Hackage tree as of May 2011](http://folk.ntnu.no/hammar/explore-hackage/).